# How to handle Quartz.net job execution events?

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz.net-3.0

I have created a generic job schedule manager class. I am using Quartz.net 3.0.7 in .net core app.

```
public class ScheduleManagerManager<TJob> : IScheduleManager where TJob : IJob
{
    private readonly string _cronExpression;
    private readonly string _jobIdentity;
    private readonly string _triggerIdentity;
    private IScheduler _scheduler;
    private IJobDetail _jobDetail;
    private ITrigger _trigger;

    public ScheduleManagerManager(string cronExpression)
    {
        _cronExpression = cronExpression;
        _jobIdentity = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _triggerIdentity = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        try
        {
            _scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

            await _scheduler.Start();

            _jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<TJob>()
                .WithIdentity(_jobIdentity)
                .Build();

            _trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity(_triggerIdentity)
                .StartNow()
                .WithCronSchedule(_cronExpression)
                .Build();

            await _scheduler.ScheduleJob(_jobDetail, _trigger);
        }
        catch (SchedulerException se)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(se.Message);
        }
    }

    public void ShutDown()
    {
        _scheduler.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

So I amusing this in applications like following:

```
var manager1 = new ScheduleManagerManager<MailSender>();
var manager2 = new ScheduleManagerManager<SmsSender>();
```

I want to add an event handler to get job data after executed the job.

```
var manager1 = new ScheduleManagerManager<MailSender>();
manager1.JobExecuted += OnJobExecuted();
```

But there is no event in Quartz.net jobs or triggers. How can I do it?

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you use multiple schedulers?

Comment: No there is no reason, but I am new at quartz.net. Actually I want to create a JobViewModel in my wpf app. And I will show the all of the status of job to user. For example job started, last run at time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*But there is no event in Quartz.net jobs or triggers.* Of course they are, they are called [Listener](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html).

Just implement `IJobListener`:

```
public class MyJobListener : IJobListener
{
    public string Name () => "MyListener";

    public Task JobToBeExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context){ }

    public Task JobExecutionVetoed(IJobExecutionContext context){ }

    public Task JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
    {
        // Do after Job stuff....
    }
}
```

And add it to your scheduler in your `ScheduleManagerManager`:

```
var myJobListener = new MyJobListener();
_scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(myJobListener, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());
```

Comment: OK. But I have a panel for every job in UI, so how can I understan which listener is executed for? I have multiple jobs.